# VBA splitting a string by 2 characters after a decimal point

Tags: string, vba, excel, split

I have the following string:

Dividends: `34.3228.1028.0028.0028.0028.0028.0028.0029.5030.50`

And I'm looking to split it so I can get it as `34.32` , `28.10` , `28.00` etc then placed into a row in excel. My issue specifically being that I'm looking to split it 2 characters to the right of the decimal point because the table data im scraping it from is it a dollar format for example:

[Picture on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8eTA.jpg)

This is what I have tried but again I have no idea how to split it based on 2 characters after the decimal point:

```
Dim eTR As Object, cTR As Object, a As Integer 
Set cTR = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
a = 0

For Each eTR In cTR
If Left(eTR.innerText, 9) = "Dividends" Then
    TR = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(a).innerText
     Debug.Print TR
    'Debug.Print a
    
End If
a = a + 1


Next

Dim s As Variant
s = (Split(TR, ".")(1))
Cells(1, 2).Value = s
Cells(1, 3).Value = s(1)
Cells(1, 4).Value = s(2)
Cells(1, 5).Value = s(3)
End Sub
```

I have also tried getting each individual table data (as it looks on the image) with the following code:

```
'get divs/share
chk = 0
dividends:
Dim eTR3 As Object, cTR3 As Object
Set cTR3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("td")
g = 0

For Each eTR3 In cTR3
If Left(eTR3.innerText, 9) = "Dividends" Then
    TR5 = doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(g).innerText
    r = 1
    i = g + 10
    For h = g To i Step 1
    TR5 = doc.getElementsByTagName("td")(h).innerText
    Cells(s + 4, r + 1).Value = TR5
    r = r + 1
    Next h
End If
g = g + 1
Next
```

But for some reason I kept getting random table data inputs that didn't belong to that row. As a way around it I thought of grabbing the table row and splitting the string up.

Comment: is the string already in excel? if an excel formula was available would that be suitable or are you specifically looking for VBA?

Comment: Can ou have more than 3 character in front of the . can you have less than 2 characters in front of the . ?  Will there always be 10 numbers total to be separated?

Comment: Looking at your code, you are attempting to concatenate the results, and then you are turning around and trying to split the results into individual cells.  Why not skip the string building and put the data directly into an array or cells?

Answer (score 1):

Excel Solution without VBA.

Assuming your string is in the A column and there are 10 numbers within the string to be pulled out.

In column M or further to the right use:

```
=FIND(".",$A$1,L1+1)
```

Ensure the column to the left of this formula is empty.  Copy the fomula to the right for 10 columns.  In my test case it was to column V.  This will return the position of every . in the string.  If you copy far enough to the right it will eventually return an error indicating there are no further . in the string to be found.

In column B use the following formula:

```
=MID(A1,5,M1-2)
'or if you want it as a number and not a string
=MID(A1,5,M1-2)*1
```

Its unique as it is the start of your data and the pattern has not started yet.  You know the first number will always start as the 5th character as DATA is 4 characters long.  The M1-2 tells how many characters to return based on the position of the decimal point.

In column C use this formula which can be copied right since the pattern repeats:

```
=MID($A1,N1-(N1-M1-3),(N1-M1))
'or if you want it as a number and not a string
=MID($A1,N1-(N1-M1-3),(N1-M1))*1
```

Copy that to the right 9 time and in the test case to column K  It is basically measuring the distance between . and determining how many characters to go back from the current decimal and how many character to return as the number.

you can now copy B1:V1 down for each new string you put in column A.  When you are done, you can copy and paste values if you like or work with as is.

Proof of concept

I have the results on staggered rows in the image to save on space and show all the points.  Also please not that since some of the numbers end in either a single or double tailing zero excel will not display them unless you format the cells.  In the image row 2 is returning the results as a string, and row 4 is returning the results as a number.

[image]

Comment: IF you need a pure VBA solution, you have a thought process here you could convert to VBA.  Also if you need a VBA solution only then you should change the tag from excel to excel-VBA

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the reply ! yeah this definitely helps me gather an idea.

Comment: I think with the VBA route, split will get you started, but then you are going to need to swap characters around from each of the array elements to build your number.  might be a bit of a pain in the arse.  You might be better off stepping through your string until your count is +2 after the count of where you come across a .  Store the string to that point then start building a new string.

Answer (score 1):

Need more technic and make sure that you need 2 digits decimal point.
Thanks @Forward Ed for the idea.

Please try:

```
' This sub is example to call splittext() function
Sub test()
Dim retArr() As String

retArr = splittext("Dividends34.3228.1028.0028.0028.0028.0028.0028.0029.5030.50")

' us reArr to do other stuff here
End Sub


Function splittext(str) As String()
Dim startPos As Integer
Dim splitArr() As String
Dim arrSize As Integer

str = Replace(str, "Dividends", "")

startPos = 1
arrSize = 0
Do While InStr(startPos, str, ".") > 0
    ReDim Preserve splitArr(arrSize)

    splitArr(arrSize) = Mid(str, startPos, InStr(startPos, str, ".") + 3 - startPos)
    arrSize = arrSize + 1
    startPos = InStr(startPos, str, ".") + 3
Loop

splittext = splitArr
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA thought:

I dont have your linked document to test with, but what about this concept:

```
Sub test()
Dim eTR As Object, cTR As Object
Dim a As Integer
Dim s() As Variant

Set cTR = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
ReDim s(1)

a = 0

For Each eTR In cTR
    If Left(eTR.innerText, 9) = "Dividends" Then
        TR = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(a).innerText
        Debug.Print TR
        'Debug.Print a
        s(a) = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr")(a).innerText
    End If
    a = a + 1
    ReDim Preserve s(a)
Next

'this range needs to be equal in size to your array.
Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, a+1)).Value = s

End Sub
```

VBA is not my strong point so there may be some huge syntax issues in there but can you see where I was going with writing directly to an array/cells?  You do it at the same point where you build your string.